# Windows Event Id 60605 on Azure VM w/SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a SQL cluster in an Azure environment that experienced a failover/recovery incident about a week ago.  Since shortly after that, this appears every 30 seconds in the Event Viewer on the primary database node:

**Event 60605**, Microsoft SQL Server Server Status Reporting

[Error] ConnectivityReportTcpPortUnknown: Could not determine sqlPort for MSSQLSERVER

I'm not 100% certain that it is related to the failover, but it seems so.  I've searched and can't find anything on this particular error code.  It most certainly reeks of a monitor or related event, as it's pretty consistent in its frequency.

After researching Azure logs (which not only report nothing relating to this event, but nothing about our failover event that was network connectivity related, also!)

I've disabled all third-party monitoring that we have on that node, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured with the low response, this must be a bug.  After talking with Microsoft, it turns out, in fact, that it is a bug with the **Microsoft SQL Server IaaS Agent** that runs on Azure VMs.  Turns out that the agent handles some of the new Automatic Patching and Automatic Backup features on Azure, but unfortunately, does not support SQL installations that listen on multiple ports (as ours does).

Two oddities, this only started a week ago (and the service was updated recently), and even in Manual Startup mode, it restarts itself when it's off.

Microsoft has confirmed that this indeed is a bug.